# Best way to parse specific value from string

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I want to parse the floating-point data S value 0.2254 from the following string. What is the best method to do that?

```
"content": "{\"data S, T, BV\": \"[0.2254],[63.290913252460534],[0.0]\"}"
```

I am attempting to parse it with JSON? I can get the Key and Value fields but then don't know what to do with that.

I have tried this approach:

```
var sensorData = await GetDataAsync();
var sensorDataArray = JArray.Parse(sensorData);
foreach (JObject obj in sensorDataArray)
   foreach (KeyValuePair<String, JToken> field in obj)
      if (field.Key == "content")
      {
        //Now I want to parse the contents of field.Value 
        //field.Value contains:  data S, T, BV: "[0.2254],[63.290913252460534],[0.0]"
      }
```

I don't know the best method to extract the 0.2554 from the field.Value contents.

Comment: Can you give a more exact example input? It seems you have a JSON string _within_ a JSON property value. Do you control the format of this input?

Comment: I am retrieving this from a query to a SoraCom website API. This is what is returned from the following call: ```var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);```:

 {
    "content": "{\"data S, T, BV\": \"[0.2254],[63.290913252460534],[0.0]\"}",
    "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
    "time": 1707417501679
  },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have JSON escaped within the string value of JSON. This means you need to parse it twice.

You have this input JSON

```
{
  "content": "{\"data S, T, BV\": \"[0.2254],[63.290913252460534],[0.0]\"}",
  "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
  "time": 1707417501679
}
```

```
var sensorData = "{ \"content\": \"{\\\"data S, T, BV\\\": \\\"[0.2254],[63.290913252460534],[0.0]\\\"}\", \"contentType\": \"application/octet-stream\", \"time\": 1707417501679 }";

// step 1, get the value of the "content" property
var contentPropertyValue = JObject.Parse(sensorData)["content"].Value<string>();

// step 2, reparse the value as JSON
var parsedContentValue = JObject.Parse(contentPropertyValue);

// step 3, get the value of the "data S, T, BV" property
var dataPropertyValue = parsedContentValue["data S, T, BV"].Value<string>();
// dataPropertyValue is now "[0.2254],[63.290913252460534],[0.0]" as a string

// step 4, split by commas, get the first element, remove braces, and parse as double
var finalValue = double.Parse(
    dataPropertyValue
    .Split(',')
    [0] // first element of split results
    [1..^1]); // take out braces, which are always indexes 0 and "last"
// finalValue is 0.2254 as a double
```

There are a number of nullability warnings with this code. Add null checking as needed for your scenario.

Comment: I'm trying that but it is crashing on the Step 1...goes to ExecutionContext.cs callback.Invoke(state); sensordata has mutliple elements, so I thought to put ```var contentPropertyValue = JObject.Parse(sensorData)[0]["content"].Value<string>()```; but it still crashes.

Comment: `ExecutionContext.cs callback.Invoke(state)` doesn't really mean anything to me. Consider making a [mre]. Here's mine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fcPw5J

Comment: Steps 2-4 work perfectly. So, I substituted Step 1 with: ```var contentPropertyValue = field.Value.Value<string>();``` and it works! Thank you!!!